# Python Websockets Module has no attribute

Tags: python, websocket

I have this python script that sends a WebSocket message to my python server. But it keeps throwing errors. I have seen these errors before, but I can't seem to fix it. I use the `2.7.x` version.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import websocket
import sys
val = sys.argv[1]
ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://ipaddress:9001")
ws.send(val)
ws.close()
```

The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://ipaddress:9001")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you've installed the wrong library (`websocket`)
try installing `websocket-client`

```
$ pip install websocket-client
```

and then your code must work just fine

Comment: did that already heres what it said 'Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): websocket-client in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

Comment: any other suggestions, i just upgraded it and still no luck

Comment: try `pip uninstall websocket` and `pip install websocket-client` again

Comment: I had this problem but it was because I had a folder called `websocket` in the same dir

Answer (score 25):

See the answer by falsetru here: [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141689/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-websocketapp)

"
Make sure that you didn't name your file as websocket.py; Otherwise, it will prevent import of the desired third-party module websocket; because your module is searched first according to sys.path module search path.

Rename your module to other name, and make sure to clean websocket.pyc if it was generated."

Comment: For me it was "websockets.py".