# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'

Tags: python, json, api, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to connect to an API with python, using WebSocketApp, and I cannot seem to do it. No matter what I try, I keep getting this error:

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'**

Here is the simple code I am using

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'data':'value'})
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('data update: %s' % message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "appurl"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, all the solutions I have found online have not worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

It looks like you're trying to use features of the `websocket-client` package and not just the `websocket` package.  Pip-install `websocket-client` from the command line (or install it using whatever other package manager you have), then try running your code again.

```
pip install websocket-client
```

Answer (score 31):

In this case, You should uninstall the possible inconsistent previous versions and install websocket-client again:

```
pip uninstall websocket-client
pip uninstall websocket
```

an then install a new version:

```
pip install websocket-client
```

Answer (score 25):

Make sure that you didn't name your file as `websocket.py`; Otherwise, it will prevent import of the desired third-party module `websocket`; because your module is searched first according to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) module search path.

Rename your module to other name, and make sure to clean `websocket.pyc` if there it is.

Comment: In my case I named the file as socket.py changing it to something else did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be generated because the version. Version v1.3 and above does me the same problem but installing v1.2.3 the issue disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you possibly installed both `websocket` and `websocket-client`.
Remove `websocket` and just let `websocket-client`

Comment: This answer does not add much to the answers  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42144096 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53444938