# Can you fix my 'websockets AttributeError' problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, attributeerror

I have tried to install and unistall the websockets module but whenever I import it, it throws an error. What do I need to do to stop this error?

I have tried to install and unistall the websockets module from `pip install websockets` and `pip uninstall websockets`.

Here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\NewProject\RawDiscordBot\client.py", line 1, in <module>
    import websockets
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import *
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\auth.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InvalidHeader
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\exceptions.py", line 294, in <module>
    class AbortHandshake(InvalidHandshake):
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\websockets\exceptions.py", line 305, in AbortHandshake
    self, status: http.HTTPStatus, headers: HeadersLike, body: bytes = b""
AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'HTTPStatus'
[Finished in 0.907s]
```

There should be no errors when I import it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40212593/152016 check the solution on this thread

Comment: Do you have a file named `http.py` in your project? If you do, that will hide the standard `http` module, causing this error.